# Error: @dagger.android.ContributesAndroidInjector was used, but dagger.android.processor.AndroidProcessor was not found

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I am trying to setup Dagger 2.12 and I'm getting this error:

**error: @dagger.android.ContributesAndroidInjector was used, but dagger.android.processor.AndroidProcessor was not found on the processor path**

Here's how I've configured Dagger:

My Application class:

```
public final class App extends android.app.Application implements HasActivityInjector {

    @Inject
    DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> activityInjector;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        DaggerAppComponent.builder().build().inject(this);
    }

    @Override
    public AndroidInjector<Activity> activityInjector() {
        return activityInjector;
    }
}
```

ActivityBindingModule:

```
@Module
public abstract class ActivityBindingModule {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = SearchActivityModule.class)
    abstract SearchActivity searchActivity();
}
```

SearchActivityModule:

```
@Module
public class SearchActivityModule {

    @Provides
    public SearchActivityDelegate getDelegate(SearchActivity searchActivity) {
        return searchActivity;
    }

    @Provides
    public SearchActivityPresenter providePresenter(SearchActivity searchActivity) {
        return new SearchActivityPresenter(new OtherDependency(), searchActivity);
    }
}
```

AppModule:

```
@Module(includes = { AndroidInjectionModule.class, ActivityBindingModule.class })
public abstract class AppModule {

}
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this error?

Comment: Do you have in your gradle file `annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.12'` ?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, I have this dependency in my build.gradle `annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.12'`.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Have you had any luck with it?

Comment: In my case, I am using Kotlin. I was able to get rid of the problem by replacing `annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:${daggerVersion}"` with `kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:${daggerVersion}"`

How does your app/build.gradle looks like?

Comment: Any fixes? I just came across the same issue.

Comment: I think that the problem was caused by Dagger related Gradle dependencies not being configured correctly.

Answer (score 50):

Go to your module level `build.gradle`, under

`annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:[YOUR VERSION NUMBER]'`,

add:

`kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:[YOUR VERSION NUMBER]'`.

Comment: If you are using Modularization then we should put kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:[YOUR VERSION NUMBER]' at module level as well.

Comment: I have both as my code is a mix of java and kotlin. I am still getting that error

Answer (score 8):

the only solution for me was using old version of dagger (2.16)

```
kotlin version : 1.2.71
// dagger
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.16'
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.16'
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.16"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.16"
```

Comment: Faced with same issue - after update Dagger from 2.16 to 2.17 it shows error `Activity cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method`, but  I have @ContributesAndroidInjector for this Activity. Was you able to solve it with latest Dagger version?

Answer (score 7):

Probably you would have missed the following dependency.

```
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:' + yourDaggerVersion
```

Answer (score 6):

**For Java**

Add this to your build.gradle

```
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$dagger_version"
```

**For Kotlin**

Add this to your build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

 kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$dagger_version"
```